# Table, print number of rows per selected field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am executing a Splunk query as below:

```sql
myusername response_status="401" | 
  table website website_url user_name transaction_name user | 
    dedup website transaction_name
```

I am getting output with filtered unique rows with `website` and `transaction_name`

How can I get the count or number of rows for each `website`?

Answer (score 0):

Counting is the job of the `stats` command.

```
myusername response_status="401" 
| dedup website transaction_name
| table website website_url user_name transaction_name user 
| stats count by website
```

Answer (score 0):

[`| stats count`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) is going to be your friend - and it'll be faster than trying to use [`dedup`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/dedup), too:

```
myusername response_status="401" 
| stats count by website website_url user_name transaction_name user
| fields - count
```

And if you want to then merely have a count of websites *inside* that list, add this:

```
| stats count by website
```